# Como contar registros após uma data especifica no Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou criando uma API em NodeJs usando o Sequelize pra facilitar a manipulação de dados de um banco de dados MySQL. Tenho uma lista de agendamentos de consultas e preciso contar quantas consultas um paciente tem a partir da data de hoje.

Vi na documentação que usando `[Op.gte]` eu consigo filtrar uma idade ou coisas que envolvam números inteiros. Mas tentei usar com o Moment.js e com a função `Date` e não funcionou.

Tentei o seguinte, sem sucesso:

```
const pacienteConsultas = await sequelize.models.consulta.count({
  where: {
    paciente_id: paciente_id,
    data_hora: [Op.gte]: Date.now()
  }
});
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está passando um valor inválido como objeto: `data_hora: [Op.gte]: Date.now()`

O correto seria `data_hora: { [Op.gte]: Date.now() }`

Se com `Date.now()` não funcionar, use `new Date()`. Você pode encontrar um exemplo similar com `Date` na [documentação](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#examples-with--code-op-and--code--and--code-op-or--code-).

---

Caso você queira adicionar mais de uma condição para a mesma coluna, o procedimento é similar, colocando todas as condições dentro de um único objeto com o nome da coluna:

```js
/* Selecionar data_hora entre hoje e amanhã (considerando o dia e hora) */
{
  where: {
    data_hora: {
      [Op.gte]: new Date(),
      [Op.lte]: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fiz a modificação para `data_hora: { [Op.gte]: Date.now() }` mas mesmo assim o erro continuou. Mas encontrei o erro. O `[Op.gte]` parece estar obsoleto. Modifiquei pra  `data_hora: { $gte: Date.now() }` e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @BobNunes O objeto `Op` não está obsoleto, você pode conferir na [documentação oficial](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators) da versão mais recente. Talvez esteja importando errado.

Comment: Encontrei essa informação na [documentação](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#deprecated--operator-aliases). Na v4 ainda funcionava. Mas pra v6 que eu estou usando, não.